# How to model many-to-many relationship between users and tenants on Google Identity Platform?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

In some B2B applications that employ multi-tenancy, a single user can belong to multiple tenants. Slack, for example, allows the same user (email+password combination) to view all the workspaces (tenants) they belong to and alternate between them seamlessly. As users switch workspaces, the application switches context to the selected workspace, loading workspace-specific entities such as channels, messages, and threads.

**Is it possible to do something similar with Google Identity Platform (GIP)?**

I understand that in multi-tenancy in GIP, all users are scoped to zero or one tenants. If a person needs to belong to 2 tenants, 2 users must be created - each with their unique `uid`. This is not a big deal when users sign up with Federated Identity Providers. They see a consent screen twice, confirm, and the application can apply some logic to know they are the same person. For example, it can hash their email address, and link the two tenants to it.

But if users log in with email+password, such approach requires users to maintain two passwords for the same service, diminishing the user experience.

I imagine that one solution is to disable multi-tenancy and store the user-to-tenant links in Firestore, or perhaps as a custom claim so that Firestore Security Rules checks don't require an extra read on every request. However, this might make it harder to enforce different authentication requirements for different tenants. For example, a user may switch context to a tenant that requires 2FA as part of their policy, and it could be advantageous to have GIP manage that part.

Are there better approaches for such a scenario?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mix authentication and authorization? Multi-tenant App and Multi-tenant user directory? IMO, you have a multi-tenant app, with a single tenant user directory to authenticate them, and then manage the authorization by yourselves (with permissions stored in Firestore for instance)

Comment: Thank you Guillaume. Hmm... I may have been mixing these. I was thinking of using the tenant_id as workspace identifier, but rethinking this, it is indeed an authorization concern. Do I understand correctly that each tenant in GIP is actually an Identity Provider (IdP)? And that the same identity can never be "provided" by more than one tenant, as IdPs own those identities by definition?

Comment: Yes, each identity in each tenant is "unique". Technically unique. If the same user register the same email in different tenant, each tenant consider it as unique and there is no pass through the other tenant.

Comment: Hi, @AmitA! Did @guillaume blaquiere’s comments solve your problem?